# Swift -meaning of viewportSize parameter of projectPoint(_:orientation:viewportSize:)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, cgsize

The Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923538-projectpoint) for

```
func projectPoint(_ point: simd_float3, orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, viewportSize: CGSize) -> CGPoint
```

says:

> viewportSize
>
> The size, in points, of the view in which the camera image is to be presented.

I'm not clear what **the view in which the camera image is to be presented** means? Does that mean that I should put in the screen dimensions for the **viewportSize**?

```
let screenDimensions = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
let position = node.position

camera.projectPoint(simd_float3(position), orientation: .portrait, viewportSize: screenDimensions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923538-projectpoint) also said:

> Return Value
>
> The projection of the specified point into a 2D pixel coordinate space whose **origin** is in the **upper left corner** and **whose size matches that of the viewportSize parameter**.

This suggests that you can put whatever size you want. The screen dimensions would be suffice if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `view.bounds.size` corresponding to the view you are projecting into.

Comment: This does not adress the question.